# Add tooltips to eric hynds multi select dropdown

Tags: jquery, multi-select, dropdownbox

I am using the Jquery based multi select dropdown provided by Eric Hynds.

I would like to add tooltip to the selection button and also each item in the dropdown list. The reason - I truncate the text in both the display and the selection list and tooltip is supposed to show the full text. But I cannot find any documentation on how to add this. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rahul. I didnt directly use li, but that did give me an idea. The control internally converts each li item to have a checkbox and a span with text. I gave a class to that particular span control. Before truncating the text, I updated the title property with the text.

```
$(".truncate").each(function(){
  $(this).attr('title', $(this).html());
});
```

Thanks for your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

your option will get converted to li tags when you use this plugin so give them attribute title this

```
$('li').attr('title','tooltip text');
```